# Select2 set selected values with ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax

When the page loads i load some data into the select box and with an ajax request i return json fields that have been selected previously.

How can i achieve that select2 set some items to selected with an ajax request?

My json simply returns an id and text.

My ajax request, which doesn't have any functionality yet:

```
// Get permissions
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "/Files/GetFolderPermissions",
    data: { folderId: folderId }
}).success(function (data) {
    // Do stuff
    //$('#EditFolder #FolderActionModel_ValueRole')
}).error(function () {
    alert('Ajax call is mislukt, kon de rollen niet ophalen');
}).always(function () {
    hideLoadingScreen();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some examples I made for you 
It depends on your select2 format

```
$("#yourSelect2Selector").select2({
        id: function(e) {return e.name;},
        placeholder: "Place holder is here",
        allowClear: true,
        width: 'resolve',
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {callback([]);},
        formatResult: function(item) {return item.name;},
        formatSelection: function(item) {
            return item.name;
        }
    });
}
```

Set selected using json object

```
$("#yourSelect2Selector").select2("data", {name: 'My name is ...'});
```

Or putting data as a string

```
$("#yourSelect2Selector").select2("data",'Your data is here')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           // Get permissions
               $.ajax({
                   type: "Get",
                   url: "/Files/GetFolderPermissions",
                   data: {
                       folderId: folderId
                   },
                   dataType:"JSON"
               }).success(function (data) {                       
                    var  id = data.id
                    $('#select2 option[value="'+id+'"]').attr('selected','selected');

               }).error(function () {
                   alert('Ajax call is mislukt, kon de rollen niet ophalen');
               }).always(function () {
                   hideLoadingScreen();
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

The end result was actually quite easily, i couldn't find anywhere in the documentation how i could auto select values with an ajax call.

Writing the code 5 minutes, finding the solution about 3 hours..

You can simply give select2 an array of the items that needs to be selected.

So in my case it was:

```
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                       var selectedValues = [];
                       $.each(json, function(bb) {
                           selectedValues.push(json[bb].Id);
                       });
                       $(".search").select2('val', selectedValues);
```